# How to write file as UTF-8 with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write some text from an AppleScript as .json to a file on desktop. However I can't figure out how to make sure it writes as UTF-8.

*My current code looks like this:*

```
set fileContent to "This is some text content with æøå letters"

set this_data to fileContent

set target_file to (((path to desktop folder) as string) & (time string of (current date)) & "_myfile.json")

set append_data to true

try
   set the target_file to the target_file as string
   set appleScriptfilePath to target_file as string
   set the open_target_file to open for access file target_file with write permission
   if append_data is false then set eof of the open_target_file to 0
   write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof
   close access the open_target_file
on error
   try
       close access file target_file
   end try
end try
```

I see people referencing "as Â«class utf8Â»", but I can't figure out how to integrate  it into my code.

What's the best way of making sure it gets saved as UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The people are right, just add `as «class utf8»`

```
write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof as «class utf8»
```

Of course you have to append `as «class utf8»` as well when you `read` the file and the file is UTF8 encoded.

And you can delete these two redundant lines

```
set the target_file to the target_file as string
set appleScriptfilePath to target_file as string
```

Comment: curious what the «» symbol is called. is this used frequently? I couldn't find any documentation on applescript using this. (at some places they said that we could replace these with "", but it doesn't work in this case)

Comment: It's called "chevron raw syntax" (not officially), please see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_raw_data.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH225-SW1